# How to make an App prompt for screen capture permissions in macOS

Tags: macos, privacy, app-bundle

I wrapped a bash script in an app bundle. The directory structure looks like this:

```
screencapture.app
└── Contents
    ├── Info.plist
    ├── MacOS
    │   └── screencapture
    └── Resources
        └── screencapture.icns
```

I reduced `screencapture` to the following code:

```
#!/bin/zsh

screencapture -C -t jpg -x $HOME/Desktop/screen.jpg
```

When I run the executable `screencapture` from the `MacOS` folder in terminal, macOS prompts for screen capture permissions for `Terminal`. When I execute the app, nothing like this happens and the screenshots taken, are empty. How can I provoke a prompt?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no. What I did as a workaround was wrapping the script in Apple Script and export an App from Script Editor.